# AlertController, change message and close after amount of time

Tags: ios, swift

It wants to change title and message into an alert when is active, that works, but doesn't close after a certain amount of time. why ?

```
func showInfo(title: String, notify: String, waitSeconds: Int) {
    
        if (alertTask != nil) {
            alertTask?.title = title
            alertTask?.message = notify
        }
        
        alertTask = UIAlertController(title: title, message: notify, preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alertTask!, animated: true, completion:{ [self] in
            alertTask!.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            alertTask!.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertControllerBackgroundTapped)))
            })
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(waitSeconds), repeats: false, block: { [self] _ in alertTask!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)} )
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't recreate `alertTask` if it already exists, so just return after you change the title/message:

```
if (alertTask != nil) {
    alertTask?.title = title
    alertTask?.message = notify
    return
}
```

If you want to reset or change the dismissal timer when the title/message is changed you'll need to store the Timer as an instance variable, invalidate it when the method is called and reassign it:

```
var alertTimer: Timer?

func showInfo(title: String, notify: String, waitSeconds: Int) {

    alertTimer?.invalidate()
    alertTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(waitSeconds), repeats: false, block: { [self] _ in alertTask!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)} )

    if (alertTask != nil) {
        alertTask?.title = title
        alertTask?.message = notify
        return
    }

    alertTask = UIAlertController(title: title, message: notify, preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alertTask!, animated: true, completion:{ [self] in
        alertTask!.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        alertTask!.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertControllerBackgroundTapped)))
    })
}
```